# Need help to display JSON data

Tags: php, json

I am requesting a JSON data feed and getting a successful return of data. I am trying to create the PHP code to display the results on my website and I'm a bit stuck on part of it. I have spent days trying to figure it out and have done numerous searches.

I have shown the JSON data returned below and have split it into three parts to show where my problem is. The central part within the square brackets I can show OK with the code I have worked out, also shown further down. But the first part and the very final part I just cannot work out.

```
{"status":"success","postcode":"CC3 3FF","postcode_type":"full","url":"https:\/\/propjsondata.co.uk\/draw?input=AA3+3FF","type":"terraced_house","max_age":18,"data":{"points_analysed":50,"radius":"1.12","date_earliest":"2019-01-14","date_latest":"2020-02-14","average":266,"70pc_range":[228,316],"80pc_range":[218,350],"90pc_range":[216,361],"100pc_range":[123,493],"raw_data":

    ///With the first part it doesn’t work how do I code this to display///The following between the square brackets displays fine///

[{"date":"2019-11-14","address":"20, Crowhurst Road, AA3 3JW","price":247000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":678,"price_per_sqf":364,"distance":"0.07"},{"date":"2019-08-16","address":"23, Crowhurst Road, AA3 3JW","price":225000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1033,"price_per_sqf":218,"distance":"0.07"},{"date":"2019-02-26","address":"27, Crowhurst Road, BB3 3JW","price":246000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":775,"price_per_sqf":317,"distance":"0.07"},{"date":"2019-05-31","address":"39, Papillon Road, CC3 3JG","price":231000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":732,"price_per_sqf":316,"distance":"0.16"},{"date":"2019-09-27","address":"85, Creffield Road, CC3 3JB","price":352000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1152,"price_per_sqf":306,"distance":"0.35"},{"date":"2019-04-08","address":"67, Creffield Road, DD3 3JB","price":385000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1087,"price_per_sqf":354,"distance":"0.35"},{"date":"2019-07-05","address":"61, Butt Road, DD3 3DG","price":238000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":840,"price_per_sqf":283,"distance":"0.37"},{"date":"2019-09-13","address":"83, New Kiln Road, DD3 3QL","price":280000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1033,"price_per_sqf":271,"distance":"0.42"},{"date":"2019-03-22","address":"74, North Station Road, EE1 1SE","price":221000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1798,"price_per_sqf":123,"distance":"0.45"},{"date":"2019-01-14","address":"6, Garland Road, FF2 7GD","price":272000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":1170,"price_per_sqf":232,"distance":"0.46"},{"date":"2019-09-20","address":"33, Wickham Road, GG3 3ED","price":280000,"bedrooms":3,"type":null,"sqf":775,"price_per_sqf":361,"distance":"0.48"}]

   ///if I add this it stops working how do I code this to display, happy to leave out though///

},"process_time":"2.53"}
```

After lots of reading this is how far I have got with the code as I say the main part between the square brackets displays but I can't sort the top or bottom parts to display.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  padding: 10px;
}
</STYLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE>

<?php
$url= 'https://81b.co.uk/sold_prices.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$resultdata = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($resultdata as $data => $value)

    echo '<tr><td>'.$value ["date"] .'</td><td>'.$value ["address"] .'</td><td>'.$value [“price”]  .'</td><td>'.$value [“bedrooms”]  .'</td><td>'.$value [“type”]  .'</td><td>'.$value [“sqf”]  .'</td><td>'.$value [“price_per_sqf”]  .'</td><td>'.$value [“distance”]  .'</td></tr>';
?> 

</TABLE>  
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: From looking at your JSON, I don't really understand how your current code is working. Are you sure `$json = file_get_contents($url);` matches what you posted? When I go to the link in your question, I don't get the same JSON that you posted, it only includes the "square bracket" part.

Comment: switching out all the fancy quotes `“` would be a good start, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for looking I have now added the complete json returned to the url stated. I had cut it down whilst testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, it appears that the JSON you're getting back from your property search API looks like this:

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "postcode":"CC3 3FF",
   "postcode_type":"full",
   "url":"https:\/\/propjsondata.co.uk\/draw?input=AA3+3FF",
   "type":"terraced_house",
   "max_age":18,
   "data":{
      "points_analysed":50,
      "radius":"1.12",
      "date_earliest":"2019-01-14",
      "date_latest":"2020-02-14",
      "average":266,
      "70pc_range":[
         228,
         316
      ],
      "80pc_range":[
         218,
         350
      ],
      "90pc_range":[
         216,
         361
      ],
      "100pc_range":[
         123,
         493
      ],
      "raw_data":[
         {
            "date":"2019-11-14",
            "address":"20, Crowhurst Road, AA3 3JW",
            "price":247000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":678,
            "price_per_sqf":364,
            "distance":"0.07"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-08-16",
            "address":"23, Crowhurst Road, AA3 3JW",
            "price":225000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1033,
            "price_per_sqf":218,
            "distance":"0.07"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-02-26",
            "address":"27, Crowhurst Road, BB3 3JW",
            "price":246000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":775,
            "price_per_sqf":317,
            "distance":"0.07"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-05-31",
            "address":"39, Papillon Road, CC3 3JG",
            "price":231000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":732,
            "price_per_sqf":316,
            "distance":"0.16"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-09-27",
            "address":"85, Creffield Road, CC3 3JB",
            "price":352000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1152,
            "price_per_sqf":306,
            "distance":"0.35"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-04-08",
            "address":"67, Creffield Road, DD3 3JB",
            "price":385000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1087,
            "price_per_sqf":354,
            "distance":"0.35"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-07-05",
            "address":"61, Butt Road, DD3 3DG",
            "price":238000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":840,
            "price_per_sqf":283,
            "distance":"0.37"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-09-13",
            "address":"83, New Kiln Road, DD3 3QL",
            "price":280000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1033,
            "price_per_sqf":271,
            "distance":"0.42"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-03-22",
            "address":"74, North Station Road, EE1 1SE",
            "price":221000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1798,
            "price_per_sqf":123,
            "distance":"0.45"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-01-14",
            "address":"6, Garland Road, FF2 7GD",
            "price":272000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":1170,
            "price_per_sqf":232,
            "distance":"0.46"
         },
         {
            "date":"2019-09-20",
            "address":"33, Wickham Road, GG3 3ED",
            "price":280000,
            "bedrooms":3,
            "type":null,
            "sqf":775,
            "price_per_sqf":361,
            "distance":"0.48"
         }
      ]
   },
   "process_time":"2.53"
}
```

And that in your above example you've cropped out the `raw_data` array containing the actual property results.

The complete JSON data appears to have three tiers in it. First there is the root containing some metadata relating to your search (the search status was successful, you searched for houses in postcode "CC3 3FF", etc). Within this there is a property called `data`, which is an object containing more metadata regarding the results of the search. Then within *that* there's a property called `raw_data` which is an array of the actual results.

If you want to print those results you need to access this `raw_data` array and iterate over it after your json_decode. Take a look at the below example - I've put the values inline in the HTML to try and make it more readable for you, along with an example of how to access the top-level data (in this case the postcode):

```
<?php
    $url= 'https://81b.co.uk/sold_prices.json';

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $resultData = json_decode($json, true);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
              border: 1px solid black;
            }
            th, td {
              padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Search for houses near <?php echo $resultData['postcode']; ?></h1>
        <table>
            <?php foreach ($resultData['data']['raw_data'] as $property) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $property['date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['address']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['bedrooms']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['type']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['sqf']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['price_per_sqf']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $property['distance']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you that works really well. If I wanted to add in some of the data in the root/top level like 'date earliest' 'average' what is the best way to do that? Thanks very much

Comment: Your json_decode line converts the whole JSON structure to a multi-dimensional array, so you need to address the correct level of that array for the value you want. `date_earliest` is at the second level in your JSON - in the `data` object - so you could access it with `echo $resultData['data']['date_earliest']`. The same goes for `average`, as this is also in the `data` object.

Comment: Not a problem. :) If you're struggling to understand the structure of a JSON response from an API it really helps if you can view it formatted in the way I pasted that sample above - with indentation to make it more readable and show the level that properties sit at within the data structure. If you use Chrome there's an extension called "JSON Formatter" you can install which will detect JSON content and format it in a human-readable fashion - I find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON structure is an array of items, but the issue you have is that some of your items are then further arrays. This is the nature of JSON :)

```
foreach ($resultdata as $data => $value)
```

This means you're splitting your whole data array into items, which have a key and a value.  ( The variable '$data' for the key could be a bit confusing, by convention we usually use $key.)

What I think you're wanting to accomplish is that you output the field name for each item, and then it's value;

So inside that foreach() you would write:

```
echo '<td>'. $data . ' : ' . $value .'</td>';
```

You'll note the usual convention of not having a space between $value and [.

Your complexity comes that sometimes that $value is itself an array, so you want to then break that down into its sub elements too:

You could do that with a simple test, using is_array, and then act differently if it's an array to if it's a single value.  Here's a bit of a rewrite with a nested foreach, which assumes that your data only goes two levels deep.

```
foreach ($resultdata as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        // It's an array, iterate over it.
        foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
           echo '<td>'. $subkey . ' : ' . $subvalue .'</td>';
        }
    } else {
       // it's a single value
       echo '<td>'. $data . ' : ' . $value .'</td>';
    }
}
```

You can take the opportunity to filter out items you don't want, by testing for the $key contents, with something like:

```
if(!(in_array($key, ['address','postcode']))) {
```

Comment: Thanks Howard So I put in what you said the 'foreach' part and it shows the top part down to the square bracket but not what it was listing within the square brackets after that. Sorry if I'm being a bit slow should I still use some of the existing code?